# How to assign categories for products in magento Programmatically

Tags: magento, categories, product, mass-assignment

I am a newbie in magento. Basically, I want to assign multiple products to multiple categories. I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523254/magento-mass-assign-products-to-category) and I have done the following code which is working fine:

```
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();//my coustom collection
        $categorys_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);//Array of ids etc 
        if ($categorys_ids != NULL && $collection->getData()!= NULL)
            {
                foreach ($collection as $product) 
                {
                        $categories_pd = $product->getCategoryIds();                              
                        $product->setCategoryIds(array_merge($product->getCategoryIds(),array($categorys_ids)));
                        $product->save();
                }
            }
```

Now, the main issue is that when I assign set category id for the products it takes a lot of time. I have 200 products and this takes up to two minutes or so, which is a lot of time.

I was wondering if there is a way that I can assign categories to a products array instead of assigning products to categories or something that can be optimized and take less time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can assign multiple products to a category and merge with the existing products.
The example is for one category but you can turn it into a loop to make it work for more.

```
$categoryId = 6; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
//get the current products
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();
//now attach the other products.
$newProductIds = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($newProductIds as $id){
    $products[$id] = 1;//you can put any other position number instead of 1.
}
//attach all the products to the category
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
//save the category.
$category->save();
```

If you want an even faster way of doing it you can do direct inserts in the table `catalog_category_product`.
Just make sure you reindex when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, using some fast array management features from newer PHP versions:

```
<?php
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

function addProductsToCategoryId($mergeProductIds, $categoryId, $storeCode) {
    // load the $category by $categoryId
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($storeCode)->load($categoryId);
    // build a flipped array of two merged arrays (1) array keys from flipped $mergeProductIds, (2) array keys from product_id keyed array in $category
    $categoryProductIds = array_flip(array_merge(array_keys(array_flip($mergeProductIds)),array_keys($category->getProductsPosition())));
    // combine array_keys from resulting merge with a matched index array filled with '0'
    // THIS resets position of product within category, change this logic if desired
    $categoryProductIds = array_combine(array_keys($categoryProductIds), array_fill(0, count($categoryProductIds), '0'));

    $category->setPostedProducts($categoryProductIds);
    $category->save();

    // optional
    // return $categoryProductIds;
}

// optional array of category IDs to test against for nin (not in) or in a find_in_set array test
// in the optional example line below, nin (not in) is used
$categoryIds = array(5,8,9,10,11,12,45,46);

$collectionIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId($storeCode)
    // optional inclusion of join for category_id
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    // optional logic to only gather ids that are, or are not in a given categoryIds array, nin (not in) is shown in example
    // ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array('finset' => $categoryIds)))
    // optional line to test whether product is associated to ANY category
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('null' => true))
    // example qualifiers to affect gathered IDs
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'M-H%'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => '%E'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => '%E#'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => '%Euro'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => '%Euro#'))
    ->getAllIds()
    ;

// if using a return value, you can set the results of this to a variable
// to perform further operations against the resulting data
addProductsToCategoryId($collectionIds, 8, $storeCode);
```

Please note, by default my method DOES NOT preserve any position for products within categories you had set. IT WILL set all positions back to a default of '0'.

Works beautifully. Requires a reindex afterward, fast mass adding. The code is a little complex, so explaining the code in direct context comments made more sense to me in this case.

I included a lot of optional extras in here, but they are all flagged as such and fully explained.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
include '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($sku);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$product->setCategoryIds($category_id);
$product->save();
```